# MSSQL installed features

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am looking for a command simliar to the @@VERSION variable that will tell me features installed in my MSSQL instance (e.g. SSIS/SSRS etc..). Is there a simple way to pull this information through a SQL script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of these features live outside the SQL instance, so they are not query-able.  The tool provided is the [Features Discovery Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510455.aspx), which is explained in detail in [this blog post](http://sqlchad.com/?p=188).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I wonder if this information is query-able with powershell using WMI cmdlet or something of the sort.

Comment: You could use `Get-Service` to look for installed services.

Comment: @MikeFal I got a virus appear warning/quarantine from the blog post in your post JS/Agent.NKW trojan, i'm using ESET 4.0.